# Tried to create a scaffold but migration already exists in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to create a new scaffold called `Message` and got this error message:

```
Another migration is already named create_messages
```

What can I do aside from changing the name of my model/controller/views (which I don't want to do)?

The reason this is occurring is I had a previous scaffold called `Message` that I changed to a different name (ran a migration to do this along with a search and replace for all filenames and variable/class names). I understand why I get this error message, just want to know how to move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix is to rename old migration (`create_messages`) and try to generate scaffold again.

But recommendation is to have single create_messages migration so that it can be safely deleted by destroy scaffold command.

Update:

If already have Message model then no point in generating Message Scaffold, since scaffold does the same thing again with additional works like generating controller, routes etc.

Comment: I want a **complete** scaffold for `Message`. I **used** to have a different `Message` which I totally renamed (table, model, views, controller, references, etc). Is it safe to simply rename a migration file?

Comment: If you have renamed every other file then you can rename migration as well, but it is not good idea to rename migration, which can be a troublesome with multiple environments.

Comment: Don't forget to rename the class in the old migration script as well. Else, you'll get a "NameError: uninitialized constant" error when doing "rake db:migrate" after "rake db:create:all".

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a migration called create_messages you probably already have a Message model(Which means you can't have another named the same). If you have now decided you want to have a scaffold on the model to get the extra controller and view code use the following where name is the name of the column.

`rails g scaffold Message name --skip`

Comment: I updated the question to indicate that I **used** to have a scaffold called `Message` that I renamed completely. Does this `--skip` work in this case?

Comment: My solution would have been if you had a message model already. Since you renamed everything before the best bet is to do what was said above. Rename the migration and then perform a normal scaffold on your new `Message` model.`--skip` works if you have run `rails g model` and now realize you want to use a scaffold for it. An upvote would be appreciated so I can make comments.